# Understanding proprietary game texture/image format (.art)

Tags: file-format

I've been researching on how to modify the textures of Crazy Taxi 3 for a while now and I have pretty much hit a brick wall.
The game stores its texture assets in `.art` files, which, from what I understand, contain several textures in each of them, due to there being many banks of textures. There is also a `Sprites` folder containing these files that indicate the same.
A quick Google search led me to believe that this may be the [AOL Image Format](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/ART_(AOL_compressed_image)) used in its software, however AOL 9.0 kept throwing errors when trying to open the files. No dice.
After searching more I found that [PFS: First Publisher used this extension as well for its clip art](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/ART_(PFS:_First_Publisher)). The files do not exactly match [the structure documented in this wiki](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/ART_(PFS:_First_Publisher)), but every .art file has something that looks like a table of information *in that structure* at the start, and then possibly image data. I have also observed that the string `GXTX` is repeated many times, may suggest that it might be a pointer of the beginning of a new image.
Other than that, I have no idea how this file format may work. It seems like it is uncompressed image data, however after opening it in many programs I have given up and need help.

---

**UPDATE 1**:
I have found a great tool called [Texturefinder](https://forum.xentax.com/blog/?p=821) that helped me figure out that these textures are compressed with DXT, however I am unsure which version, as half of a certain texture bank may look great in DXT1, while another half looks jumbled until I switch to DXT3 or 5. The container format possibly has information on which algorithm to use in a table before the images, as at the start of each texture file there is plenty of non-image data, or at least data that this tool can not decide. Here are a few examples of this working in one algorithm vs the other:

[image: DXT1a @ 512px width] [image: DXT3 @ 256px width]

So, here is an updated list of what I have gathered:

- `.art` files contain the string `GXTX` many times, usually followed by about 12 bytes that have small values (something like `80 00 80 00 00 80 00 00 01 00 05 00`), likely an image separator
- [The files contain many textures compressed with DXT](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/DXT)
- Textures may be compressed with differing forms of DXT (possibly DXT1 and DXT3)
- Textures in banks may have differing widths/heights
- Every texture bank has a sizeable amount of non-image data at the start
- The textures are upside down

[Here are some more samples for comparison.](https://anonfiles.com/35E491Jcn5/samples_zip)

Comment: Can you provide multiple samples of the file format? This would be helpful for finding structural commonalities between the files.

Comment: Please note that this file is not in the [AOL ART image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ART_image_file_format). The latter starts with the JG header (2 bytes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reversed 99% of the .ART file this week, here you go:

```
// header
4 bytes - total of images

// file offsets directory
  // for each image
  4 bytes - image offset in directory

// images directory
  // for each image
  4 bytes - magic (gxtx)
  2 bytes - width
  2 bytes - height
  4 bytes - image data size
  2 bytes - unknown
  2 bytes - compression type (10 = DXT1 | 11 = DXT3)
  X bytes - image data
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some research and found that the textures uses one of these formats, depending on the 2 bytes value the texture has (10, 11, 4, 5, 0 or 2063):

"DXT1, DXT3, A8R8G8B8, A4R4G4B4, R5G6B5, A1R5G5B5"